# JAX-WS webservice and @XmlAnyElement

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

So, I try to write SOAP @WebService with Spring and JAX-WS 2.2.10.

Part of incoming function parameter looks like this:

```
package com.itu.messaging.regional;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "GenericMessagePrimaryContent", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class GenericMessagePrimaryContent implements Serializable {

    @XmlAnyElement
    protected Element any;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the any property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Element }
     *     
     */
    public Element getAny() {
        return any;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the any property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Element }
     *     
     */
    public void setAny(Element value) {
        this.any = value;
    }
}
```

But, when I deploy my code (and want to see generated WSDL) - I got this exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$26 cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.core.EnumLeafInfo`.

So, the most interesting is, that exception throws in `XmlSchemaGenerator.java`, but not JAX-WS XmlSchemaGenerator, in Glassfish Metro 2.3.1 `XmlSchemaGenerator.java`.

My project has a lot of modules, but this module don't have link to metro in his pom.xml, it has only another module. Why this problem can become?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, answer is simple and strange.

All my @XmlType classes was in one java package and in one XML-namespace.

So, when I moved @XmlType classes, which contains @XmlAnyElement to another java package and XML-namespace, but all @XmlRootElement classes still stay in first package and namespace - all started working well. Strange, sad, but true.

P.S. I think, this is a bug in JAX-WS.